# Bash operator & not working

Tags: linux, bash, process, python

As per the bash reference, we can give a non-blocking command by ending it with an ampersand(&) character. However, when I try the below command its not working:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080&
```

The reason I intend to do so is that I want to start the built-in python webserver as part of another larger program which is also written in python. How do I issue this command in a non-blocking/daemon mode?
I even tried to execute this command using "subprocess.Popen()" in python which is also supposed to create a non-blocking process, but even that is not working.

EDIT: Here is the portion of my python code that starts the webserver (Adding 'nohup' seems to do the trick):

```
pid_webserver = execute("nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &",wait=False,shellexec= True)
#pid_webserver = execute("python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &",wait=False,shellexec= True)

def execute(command,errorstring='', wait = True, shellexec = True):
    try:
        print 'command=' + command
        p=subprocess.Popen("gksu '" + command + "'", shell=shellexec,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        if wait:
            p.wait()
            result=get_stdout(p)
            return result
        else:
            print 'not waiting'
            return p
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print 'error occured:' + errorstring
        return errorstring
```

Comment: Please clarify: What do you mean by "not working"? Exactly what happens, and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: As rici states, what exactly do you mean by "not working"? Works like a charm for me

Comment: Is it because you have no space between the `&` and the end of your command?

Comment: What I mean by "not working" is that it is not doing its stated purpose of creating a non-blocking process. When I issue the above command, it still blocks though its terminated by "&".

Comment: @jw013 - I tried with the space, still same results.. :-((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` works. But I think what your are looking for is `nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer &`.

But I thinks you should also look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html.

Comment: If it works, then why does my command blocks? It should just start the server and exit, right? But it doesn't.

Comment: @PrahladYeri can you post you `subprocess.Popen` line in your program with all the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the nohup idea. Its the only thing that runs as non-blocking. Otherwise, even subprocess.Popen() is blocking.

Comment: I've also updated the question with the subprocess.Popen code.

Comment: Need one more help. How do I issue "cd" and the python server at once. I tried this but its not working : "cd /mypath | nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &"   (current directory does not change)

Comment: @PrahladYeri - use a colon `;` to separate a list of commands to be run, separate the commands with `&&` to check that the first command is successful before the next runs, and so on. The `|` or "pipe" character you used redirects the output of the first command into the input of the second.

Answer (score 2):

'&' will not work here ...
It is a bash operator, in your script you are not using bash to execute the command, you are executing it from python script - that is why it will never work.

try :

```
import os
os.system("python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &")
```